# Laravel Best Practice in handling Multiple Queries and Joins

Tags: php, laravel

I need a code suggestion.

Basically I'm developing a system that requires a lot of joins and relationship in the database. Currently in Laravel I'm using **Query Builder** for Database queries in the application.

Currently I have this example of Querying in the database.

```
 $approved = DB::table('employee_overtimes as eo')
            ->select('eo.id as id', 'eo.employee_id as eo_employee_id', 'eo.overtime_date', 'eo.time_in', 'eo.time_out', 'eo.approver_id', 'eo.remarks', 'eo.status',
                'firstname','lastname','employee.employee_no', 'employee.id as employee_id', 'eo.created_at')
            ->join('employee' , 'employee.id', '=', 'eo.employee_id')
            ->where('eo.status', '=', 'Approved')
            ->orderByDesc('eo.created_at')
            ->orderBy('lastname', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

Can Anyone suggest a better approach in handling this kind of queries? Because it becoming repetitive in my controller.

Comment: Looks like you need to use relationships. Refer [Laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Sorry, but is it still possible to have a 3 or more tables using laravel relationship?

Comment: you can have as many relationships or joins as you wish. Your choice on how to do it, based on your code, really. If the code becomes repetitive, create a library or a service, and call it from your controllers instead of copy pasting it. If only a few params change, just make sure your global function can accommodate multiple case scenarios. I do lots of joins every day, nothing wrong with them. I prefer them over 6 relationships, as ido 1 query instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Its okay to use the querybuilder instead of eloquent because it is more faster and sometimes eloquent cant handle complex queries. And also, avoid using `DB::raw` because it is prone to sql injections. Please refer to this article https://kursuswebprogramming.com/perbedaan-eloquent-dan-query-builder-laravel/

And for your concern about the repetitive code, you must create your custom function or library and then you can use it in each of your controller as you wish.

Let me show you some comparison

Eloquent ORM (Execution time : 1.41 s, Queries Executed : 1000)

```
<?php

Route::get("test",function(){
    for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
         $t=new Country();
         $t->label=$i." Row";
         $t->save();
    }
}); 
?>
```

Query Builder (Execution time : 938 ms, Queries Executed : 1000)

```
<?php
Route::get("test",function(){
    for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
         DB::table("countries")->insert(["label"=>$i." Row"]);
    }
});
?>
```

Now this is a prove that Query Builder is 0.5 s faster than Eloquent.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: I just answered him my suggestion. And I think his approach is good because he is using querybuilder. I also answered his concern about the repetitive code issue sir.